# Spring Cloud Gateway Load Balancing type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Which kind of load balancing (client side or server side) is implemented when we use lb as a prefix for a url/service? How is it different from zuul? Afaik, zuul is used for server side load balancing.

Comment: It's not different than zuul. Gateway uses a client side load balancer so gateway clients don't have to

Comment: Oh, I get it now. So, gateways act as client, that's why it's called client side load balancing for them, and if we look at the overall picture, it's really server side load balancing. Is this right?

Comment: that is correct.